# cannot able to get values using any = {} in typescript angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   values: any = {};


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();
    console.log(this.values);
  }

   getValues()
   {
     this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/values').subscribe(Response => { this.values = Response},error => {console.log(error); 
     });
   }

}
```

I can able to get values from HTTP response.but I cannot able to store those values in 'values' object. getting empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place console.log within the subscribe, As it is getting called asynchronously by the time your console.log gets executed there is no result.

```
getValues()
{
     this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/values').subscribe(Response => { 
        this.values = Response;
        console.log("##Got values", this.values);
        },error => {console.log(error);      
   });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I cannot able to use these values in another component.         
                                                                                                                                       
 export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() valuesFromHome: any;
  model: any = {};
  constructor() { }

Comment: thts totally a different question